# grunt uglify from two source files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I generate two concatenated files using:

```
concat: {
    header: {
        src: [
            // these will go in header
            'assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js',
            'assets/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
            'assets/js/select2/select2.min.js',
            'assets/js/icheck/jquery.icheck.js',
            'assets/uploadify/js/jquery.fileupload.js'
        ],
        dest: 'assets/js/admin_header_common.js'
    },
    footer: {
        src: [
            'assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
            'assets/js/bootstrap-lightbox.min.js',
            'assets/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js',
            'assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
            'assets/js/common.js'
        ],
        dest: 'assets/js/admin_footer_common.js'
    }
},
```

Now I want to compress those two generated concatenated files so I did this:

```
// minify js
uglify: {
    build: {
        header: {
            src: 'assets/js/admin_header_common.js',
            dest: 'assets/js/admin_header_common.min.js'
        },
        top: {
            src: 'assets/js/admin_footer_common.js',
            dest: 'assets/js/admin_footer_common.min.js'
        }
    }
},
```

However the problem is that generated files are not getting compressed. Is above `uglify` declaration fine or I am missing something ? I just need to compress two files and generate two separate destination files.

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure it like below

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      header: {
        files: {
          'assets/js/admin_header_common.min.js': 'assets/js/admin_header_common.js'
        }
      },
      footer: {
        files: {
          'assets/js/admin_footer_common.min.js': 'assets/js/admin_footer_common.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Use `uglify:header` for one, `uglify:footer` for the other.